# DLL's dependency cannot be found when DLL moved to another location

Tags: c++, dll, properties, visual-studio-2017, dependencies

I'm on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, x64 build . . .

I have a DLL that I'm using in an exe project.  We'll call it, **myLibrary.dll**.  It comes with a .lib companion file as well.  The myLibrary.dll has some other DLL dependencies that it is using.  We'll call that one **theDependency.dll**.

I've linked the companion myLibrary.lib file in my project through Linker --> General --> Additional Library Dependencies properties.  Added **myLibrary.lib** to the Additional Dependencies.

When I build my project, I use post build event to copy the **myLibrary.dll** to the Release/Debug directory of my project.

This works fine.

My issue is when I try to use **myLibrary.dll** in a different exe project.  I get an error that it cannot find the **theDependency.dll**.  I've used all the same property setup as the first exe project.  As a test, I moved the build directory of the first exe project to another location (on the same computer) and I get the same error. "Cannot find **theDependency.dll**"

How is **myLibrary.dll** targeting it's dependencies?  Not sure why the 2nd project gets this error?  Also, not sure why moving the files gets this error?

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Where is `theDependency.dll` in relation to `myLibrary.dll`? Same folder? Relative path?

Comment: Check the 32-bit vs 64-bit build settings

Comment: @VladFeinstein theDependency.dll is in a different directory than myLibrary.dll.  In the myLibrary.dll project, the properties for Additional Library Directories points to the location via environment variable definition.  That's why I'm confused as to why it would work for the first exe project but not the second.

Comment: @tzg `Additional Library Directories`, I believe, help linker find the `.lib` files. It has nothing to do with run-time `dll` locations.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I was wondering about that.  Then do you know what settings or properties define where to point to the dependency dlls?

Comment: @tzg It is resolved at runtime, when none of those property play any role. The simple way is to place both DLLs in the same folder. The compex way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the path of the dll to the PATH environment variable worked for me.